# Render pixel color information in the Image Editor

Tags: shaders

I'm fairly new to Blender and really like it's capabilities.
However, coming from Maya there's one thing i really miss, I can't seem to find a eyedropper tool that shows me the color values of my rendering in a stats bar for example.

In Maya, we had something like this.

[image: Pixelviewer from Maya]

It gives the information from the cursor location in the renderview for all the passes you need while shading ( RGB values, Z-depth values, object values, etc.).

Does anyone know if Blender got something like this or maybe a addon that gives such information?

I found the Historgram in the rendering tab but it's not that useful since you need to render the image first before you can use it.

Answer (score 4):

In the image editor, hold down right-click on the image. Pixel stats will appear on the bottom of the window. This tool also works while the image is still being rendered.

Here is a demo (Notice the bottom):

[image]

Comment: X and Y are coordinates, Z is depth RGBA are scene referred values. CM RGBA are display refeerred (after the transforms set in the color management)

Comment: @Pullup Very correct

Comment: @Pullup Thanks, didn't know that :).